# Linq expression two fields inner join

Tags: c#, entity-framework

It's a simple difficult that I need help. I have a linq expression on C# that I'm trying to do but I don't know how to do that.

In this expression I just need to add an "AND" or "&&" like the code below.

```
on comentListaDef.Id equals respostaComentListaDef.IdComentListaDef &&   
RespostaComentListaDef.IdAutor = 1072
```

Comment: oh yes, sorry :( Is there a way to delete this post because is duplicated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use anonymous objects to perform `JOIN` with multiple join conditions:

```
join respostaComentListaDef in db.RespostaComentListaDef
on new { Id = comentListaDef.Id, IdAutor = 1072 } equals new { Id =  respostaComentListaDef.IdComentListaDef, respostaComentListaDef.IdAutor }
```

Comment: thank you! it worked! i had to create a new class with {get;set;} to use anonymous type.

Answer (score 1):

You should be applying that condition in a `where` before (or after) the join, not in the actual `join` expression, given that you're filtering out items from one of the sets, rather than determining which items are or are not a match between the two sets.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join by two anonymous objects with the same property names

```
join respostaComentListaDef in db.RespostaComentListaDef
on new { comentListaDef.Id, IdAutor = 1072 } equals 
   new { Id = respostaComentListaDef.IdComentListaDef, respostaComentListaDef.IdAutor }
```

Comment: very good! worked fine! like i said to @MarcinJuraszek, i had to create a new class to understand the anonymous type :)